# hidden element is not positioned correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am stuck for 1 day on the display of a hidden table in Angular.

So, I have a table with several elements

[image]

When, the user clicks on the button `1`, the second table is at the bottom.

[image]

It must be between the button 1 and the button 2.

Another example:

When, the user clicks on the button `2`, the second table must be between the button 2 and the button 3.

[image]

I really don't know how to solve this problem -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdrf9n?file=src/app/app.component.html).

I'm not sure the problem is in Angular? Maybe in HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, however, if you look at your screenshots, you can see that the bottom table does not stretch all the way to the right (it misses one column) - so if you change your colspan from 6 to 7 - it is aligned perfectly?

Comment: Besides that - if you need more flexibility than this solution can offer you - I'd recommend to not use tables (not responsive anyway) - but investigate css grid - that is way more flexible.

Comment: @MikeOne: Actually, I want my second array (hidden array) to be after the button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'after the button'... ? You mean you want to insert a row after the the row you clicked the button on?

Comment: @MikeOne: Sorry, for my english. Yes, please...

Comment: I see Naren has you covered on how to do that..;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this approach for showing for each element. We store the latest clicked index, then using `ngIf` we render the second table below the latest row that was clicked.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f7ks6n

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem - you want to insert the new table as a row under the row in which the button was clicked. The problem in your code is following: you have an `ngFor` which creates 10 rows and then under the `ngFor` you have your "result row" with the data you want to present. What you need to do is to have the "result row" inside the `ngFor`, so that you would have a result row for each row. And then apply `ngIf` on these new rows, if the correct button was clicked.

For example you click button nr. 3 => you evaluate the id and apply class `show` only to one of the result rows.

EDIT: Naren Murali code example is exactly what I mean.